# What happens when there is a NOT (~) on a bit shift operation

Tags: bit, bit-shift, bitstring

Just looking for some clarification on this homework question

The bitshift operation is ((1010 & ~(1 << 3))

So it's a left shift by 3 which would then be 0000, but with a the not, would it become 1111?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 << 3` is not `0000`, it's `1000`. Complementing that yields `0111`, which then you AND with `1010`:

```
  1010
& 0111
------
  0010
```